# Attempting to check if s3 bucket item exists within nested asyncs

Tags: amazon-s3, async-await, es6-promise, serverless-framework

I have a Serverless Lambda function that, in response to an S3 `s3:ObjectCreated` event, tries to check if a separate item exists in an S3 bucket using the following bit of code using the AWS JavaScript SDK:

```
exports.somethingSomeSomething = async (event) => {

  event.Records.forEach(async (record) => {

    let tst = await s3.headObject({
      Bucket: "mybucket",
      Key: "something.gz"
    }).promise()

    console.log(tst)
  })

};
```

I'm quite rusty with promises in JS, so I'm not sure why this bit of code doesn't work. For reference, it just dies without outputting anything.

However, the following *does* work:

```
exports.somethingSomething = async (event) => {


    let tst = await s3.headObject({
      Bucket: "mybucket",
      Key: "something.gz"
    }).promise()

    console.log(tst)
    console.log("RED")

};
```

How can I get the initial bit of code working, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your code is `async`, but the function passed to your `forEach` loop is also `async`, so you have an `async` function invoking another chunk of `async` code, therefore you lose control of the flow. Whatever is inside `forEach` will run (although anything after `forEach` will run before whatever is inside `forEach`), but it will execute asynchronously and you are unable to keep track of its execution.

But if the code, as I said, will run, why don't you see the results?

Well, that's because Lambda will terminate before that code has the chance to execute. If you run the same piece of code locally, you'll see it will run just fine, but since the original code runs on top of Lambda, you don't have control when it terminates.

You have two options here:

The easiest is to grab the first item in the Records array because s3 events send one and only one event per invocation. The reason it is an array is because the way AWS works (a common interface for all events). Anyways, your `forEach` is not using anything of the `Record` object, but still if you wanted to use any properties of it, simply reference the 0th position, like so:

```
exports.somethingSomeSomething = async (event) => {
    const record = event.Records[0]

    //do something with record

    const tst = await s3.headObject({
        Bucket: "mybucket",
        Key: "something.gz"
    }).promise()

    console.log(tst)
};
```

If you still want to use a for loop to iterate through the records (although, again, unnecessary for s3 events), use a `for of` loop instead:

```
exports.somethingSomeSomething = async (event) => {
    for (const record of event.Records) {
        // do something with record
        const tst = await s3.headObject({
            Bucket: "mybucket",
            Key: "something.gz"
        }).promise()
        console.log(tst)
    }
};
```

Since `for of` is just a regular loop, it will use the `async` from the function it's being executed on, so `await` is perfectly valid inside it.

More on [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) and [for..of](https://javascript.info/iterable)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! A no-loop scenario seems to work best for my particular use case. That said, I'm wondering why *does* it terminate for Lambda? And where is this behaviour documented for Lambda?

Comment: Thanks! Theoretically, you should be able to modify this behaviour by setting the 'callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop' to true on the `context` object, but this is an old workaround for the callback style. I personally have never tested to see if it works with `async/await`. IIRC, callbacks and promises are set in different arrays in the event loop, so I think `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` only looks if there are any pending callbacks, so my blind guess it that it would not work.

Comment: The documentation which talks about these attributes is located at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html